# Why must polymers have a repeating unit?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers, c-c-addition

In organic chemistry, we learned that small molecules can form a polymer via a process called polymerization. For example, $\ce{CH2=CH-Br}$ molecules can form the polymer

\begin{align}
\ce{nCH2=CH-Br-> -[-CH2 -}&\ce{CH -]_n -}.\\
&\;\ce{|}\\
&\ce{Br}
\end{align}

So the polymer is a periodic chain $\ce{-CH2-CHBr-CH2-CHBr-\cdots}$. But since every monomer can have two orientations ($\ce{-CH2-CHBr -}$ or $\ce{-CHBr-CH2 -}\!$), there is no requirement that all monomers must be in the same orientation, does the polymer have to be a peroidic chain? Can it be a random chain with a structure that looks like

$$\ce{-CH2-CHBr-CHBr-CH2-CHBr-CH2-CH2-CHBr-CH2-\cdots}\,?$$

Most textbooks emphasize that $n$ is random, but still assume that the unit repeats.

Comment: I recommend you look at the roots of ‘polymer’ poly means many, mer means segment, mono means one. Monomer - one segment. Polymer - many segments.

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder, the discussion is periodic vs random. I'm not sure if a random chain is actually possible, or it is simply energetically not favorable on the scale of thermal fluctuations $k_BT$.

Comment: honestly I can’t see why it couldn’t be random, I mean DNA could be random and still considered a polymer

Comment: Random chains are very much possible. Then again, _this_ particular one is probably repeating.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, entropy favors randomness, but energy favors order. For example, having two adjacent $\ce{-CHBr -}$ segments can increase the repulsion of negative charges on bromine. If entropy can overcome this, then we will have a random chain. Otherwise the chain will want to order itself.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty comprehensive answer to your own question.

Comment: That's how things would work out in theory. I'm still expecting an experienced answer that tells me what happens in practice.

Comment: Well, that's what happens in practice, too. Related reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacticity.

Comment: There is two things: The repeating unit, and its orientation. The former is always the same in your case, the latter not necessarily. Of course you can also mix monomers (doesn't always work however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entropy would favour a random orientation of each monomer unit when building up the chain, however whenever you have two different substituents at the ethylene unit, then electrostatics and sterical hindrance will make one side be preferred to make the connection to the growing chain end.

Polymers that do grow via chain growth therefore have a regular structure, but there can be defects. The defect density depends on how strong the preference for one side is during the polymerisation reaction. You can have as little as one in ten thousand. That's actually a bit of a problem, because the regularity often allows polymers to crystallise, which is important for the technical application. You want the number of defects always to be the same, because too high crystalinity makes your material brittle, too low makes it soft.

Polymers that make step growth (any two molecules randomly connect with their end groups, until you have a long chain) could be different, but also there often a regular structure occurs, because of A-B + A-B , either the A+B like to react, or A+A and B+B.

Comment: I realize this problem is related to a 1D Ising model with nearest neighbor interactions. Since the Ising model in 1D does not have a ferromagnetic phase transition at nonzero temperatures, defects are inevitable once the chain grows long (to approach the thermodynamic limit).

Comment: @ZhuoranHe No, that doesn't really apply afaik. We are not talking about a 1D crystal. The chain is flexible (rotation around sp3-bonds, ), so there is a lot of room for entropy in it. Isotactic polypropylene for example can be made practically defect-free, much less than one defect per molecule at several thousand monomers per molecule, and you could also (not only theoretically) sort out chains with a defect.

Comment: I know the chain is not straight.  In a simplified model that only cares whether adjacent monomers have the same or opposite orientations, the rotational degrees of freedom of the sp3 bonds would be uncoupled to the ordering of the orientations. To make the mean defect-free length long, we need to reduce $\exp(-\Delta E/k_BT)$ by increasing $\Delta E$, the energy cost of having a defect. If $\Delta E=10k_BT$, then the defect-free length could be $\sim 10^4$.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe The orientation of repeating units cannot reach thermodynamic equillibrium, because the activation energy to flip one unit cannot be reached without completely destroying the chain. The ends of a long gaussian chain have no way of knowing they belong the same chain. A fixed, known defect imo is not even a defect in the way Ising is looking at it. (?)

Comment: I think they still can reach equilibrium during the reaction. You see the number $n$ can randomly change. What this means is that the bonds between monomers are forming and breaking all the time. To preserve the defectless chains sifted from the reaction system, the temperature would then have to be lowered.

Comment: $n$ can only grow during most polymerisation reactions, because we are *very far* below the so called *ceiling temperature*. Once a covalent bond is made, it stays. I am very sure Ising, Peierls et al. only apply to systems with translational periodicity. A stiff chain like C=C=C=C=C=C=C would indeed be sth different, that's not a polymer like all others, and would just break when it comes close to some critical lenght.